# Spring JPA OneToMany Relationship on multiple attributes

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child`. A Parent can have multiple children and a Child can have a mother and/or father as parents. How to map this relationship?

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Parent {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    /* ... */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Child> children;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Child {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    /* ... */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "father_id")
    private Parent father;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mother_id")
    private Parent mother;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map them to separate fields in Parent:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Parent {
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Child> childrenWhoCallMeFather;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mother", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Child> childrenWhoCallMeMother;
}
```

By common sense if all children DB records are configured correctly , a parent will have :

1. Both fields are empty (i.e This parent does not have any childrens)
2. Only one field contains value while another are empty . If `childrenWhoCallMeFather` has value , this parent is father. Otherwise , this parent is mother.

But if there are one children call a parent mother , and another children call the same parent father . Then this parent will have non-empty collections on both fields if that makes sense.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that maps'em all in a single attribute, but this still works, specially as I'm using DAO classes `Response` & `Request`. so I can join the 2 collections in a single one for the *Response*